# Checking on which position is a variable in javascript array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

So here is my JavaScript array:

```
var champions = {   
    "Aatrox":["Blood Well","Dark Flight", "No Q2", "Blood Thirst", "Blood Price", "Blades of Torment", "No E2", "Massacre"],
    "Ahri":["Essence Theft","Orb of Deception", "Fox-Fire", "Charm", "Spirit Rush"],
    "Akali":["Twin Disciplines", "Mark of the Assassin", "Twilight Shroud", "Crescent Slash", "Shadow Dance"],
    "Alistar":["Trample","Pulverize","Headbutt","Triumphant Roar","Unbreakable Will"],
    "Amumu":["Cursed Touch","Bandage Toss","Despair","Tantrum","Curse of the Sad Mummy"]
};
```

Now I get a variable from a PHP form with champion name so e.g. `Akali` and also with a spell name so e.g. `Twin Disciplines` now I want to check if that spell and champion exists in my array and if so on which position it is so:

```
var championName = echo $champion;
var Spell = echo $championSpells[1][$j];
if($.inArray(championName, champions)==-1){
    var existsInArray = false;
} else{
    var existsInArray = true;
}
```

And at this point im really confused Spell is = 'Twin Disciplnes' championName is = 'Akali' so with those examples I would want to retrive 1 if it was for example 'Mark of the Assassin' I would want to retrieve 2 because it is 2nd in order.

Comment: and what language should be used?

Comment: @NinaScholz I'm not sure If you can easily use such JS array in PHP so it would be probably easier to do it in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript you can use [`Array.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) for the search of an item in an array. The result is the index starting with `0`. If not found, the `-1` is returned.

```js
var champions = {
    "Aatrox": ["Blood Well", "Dark Flight", "No Q2", "Blood Thirst", "Blood Price", "Blades of Torment", "No E2", "Massacre"],
    "Ahri": ["Essence Theft", "Orb of Deception", "Fox-Fire", "Charm", "Spirit Rush"],
    "Akali": ["Twin Disciplines", "Mark of the Assassin", "Twilight Shroud", "Crescent Slash", "Shadow Dance"],
    "Alistar": ["Trample", "Pulverize", "Headbutt", "Triumphant Roar", "Unbreakable Will"],
    "Amumu": ["Cursed Touch", "Bandage Toss", "Despair", "Tantrum", "Curse of the Sad Mummy"]
};

function getPos(o,n, s) {
    return n in o && o[n].indexOf(s);
}

document.write(getPos(champions, 'Akali', 'Twin Disciplines') + '<br>');
document.write(getPos(champions, 'Akali', 'Mark of the Assassin') + '<br>');
```